# Calculating BMR with additional if statements?

Tags: java, if-statement, int, boolean, double

i'm trying to calculate BMR with added Sedentary, Somewhat_Active, Active, and        Very_Active. The code will compile but won't compute. This is a first attempt so any advise is helpful. I have successfully created a BMR without the added category but now I am not able to get a computation. I am attempting to get just the FemaleBMR to work first before i also add on MaleBMR

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BMR2

{ 
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {

    Scanner kybd = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter Height: ");

    double Height = kybd.nextDouble ();

    System.out.print("Enter Weight: ");

    Double Weight = kybd.nextDouble ();

    System.out.print("Enter Age: ");

    int Age = kybd.nextInt ();

    double FemaleBMR = 655 + 4.3 * Weight + 4.7 * Height - 6.8 * Age;

    double MaleBMR = 66 + (6.3 * Weight) + (12.9 * Height) - (6.8 * Age);

    int choc = 230;
    System.out.println("Are you Sedentary, Somewhat_Active, Active, or Very_Active?: ");
    boolean Sedentary = kybd.nextBoolean ();
    boolean Somewhat_Active = kybd.nextBoolean();
    boolean Active = kybd.nextBoolean ();
    boolean Very_Active = kybd.nextBoolean ();

    if (Sedentary)
      System.out.println("chocolate bars for female: "+ FemaleBMR*1.2/choc);

    else if (Somewhat_Active)
    System.out.println("chocolate bars for female: "+ FemaleBMR*1.3/choc);

    else if (Active)
      System.out.println("chocolate bars for female: "+FemaleBMR*1.4/choc);

    else if (Very_Active)
      System.out.println("chocolate bars for female: "+FemaleBMR*1.5/choc);

    }
    }
```

compiles but won't compute yielding

```
java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:840)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1461)
at java.util.Scanner.nextBoolean(Scanner.java:1756)
at BMR2.main(BMR2.java:43)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)
```

Comment: You're asking it to read in a `boolean` value, but it's seeing some other input. Please post the input.

Comment: i'm not sure where I would find that other input. Again i'm new to java.

Comment: Why the ridiculous amount of vertical whitespace?

Comment: it was just more simple for me to read. I got rid of some of it if that helps.

Comment: Like chrylis was saying, you're not inputting booleans where you should be. When you run this program, after you ask the sedentary, etc. question, you're asking for four booleans. Your error is telling you that you're inputing something different for at least one of those.

Comment: okay so my input is 72 then 173 then 20 then Sedentary. i have tried all the Sedentary etc and they all result in the same error

Comment: Post *the exact characters* that you're typing in. If you're typing the word "Sedentary", that's not "true" or "false".

Comment: Okay so this time i typed in "72" then "173" then "20" then as you said "True" instead of "Sedentary" and then "False" "False" and "False" and i got the answer for Sedentary. How would I go about being able to type in Sedentary etc rather than true false false false to get the answer? would i have to use something other than boolean?

Answer (score 0):

I am seriously doubting the poster was doing lab assignment for Professor DoBeck's CS12 or CS13 class in Sierra College. I am doing the exact same thing in his class right now.

Anyways,

You should start with declaring your fields in the top. Makes it more readable and easier to debug / maintain.

Change Double Weight = kybd.nextDouble (); to double Weight = kybd.nextDouble();

For the lifestyle selection evaluator (sedentary, active, very active), use the switch statement.

Learn about switch statement here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Below is my version of it. Notice the blank spaces and proper documentation in comments to make code more readable, understandable and maintainable.

//  CODE STARTS BELOW

import java.util.Scanner;

public class BMRCalculator

{

public static void main(String args[] )

{

// fields

```
double BMRMale, BMRFemale; // male and female bmr calculation fields

double height; // inches
double weight; // pounds (lbs)

final int maleOption = 1;

final int femaleOption = 2;

int userChoice;

int age = 0;


Scanner kb = new Scanner ( System.in ); // creates a keyboard scanner object called: kb   


  System.out.print("What is your age: ");

  age = kb.nextInt();


  System.out.print("Enter your height (inches): ");

  height = kb.nextDouble();

  System.out.print("Enter your weight (pounds): ");

  weight = kb.nextDouble();




  // male or female gender selction prompt

  System.out.print ("Enter 1 for male or 2 for female gender selection: ");

  userChoice = kb.nextInt();
```

/*

***** Calories burned calculations:

***** Harris Benedict Method

***** BMR Men: = 66 + (6.23 X weight in pounds) + (12.7 X height in inches) – (6.8 X age)

***** BMR Women: = 655 + (4.35 X weight in pounds) + (4.7 X height in inches) – (4.7 X age)

*/

if (userChoice >= 1 && userChoice <= 2 )

{

```
  switch( userChoice )

  {
     case maleOption:

 //  BMR Men: = 66 + (6.23 X weight in pounds) + (12.7 X height in inches) – (6.8 X age)

     BMRMale = 66 + (6.23 * weight) + (12.7 * height) - (6.8 * age);

     System.out.println ("Your Male BMR is: " + BMRMale );


     break; // break out of maleOption


     case femaleOption:

// BMR Women: = 655 + (4.35 X weight in pounds) + (4.7 X height in inches) – (4.7 X age)


     BMRFemale = 655 + ( 4.35 * weight ) + (4.7 * height ) - (4.7 * age );

     System.out.println ("Your Female BMR is: " + BMRFemale );

     break; // break out of femaleOption




  } // end switch case
```

} // end if block

else // error displayed if 1 or 2 not entered.

```
{

     System.out.println("Invalid gender choice. Please enter 1 for male, 2 for female !");



} // end if .. else block
```

} // end main

} // end class